# How to properly install Cartaro GeoCMS?

Tags: postgis, drupal

I have been trying to install Cartaro the drupal GeoCMS for a while without success. I have properly installed Geoserver (running fine), Postgresql and postgis 1.5 enabled but when i try to install Cartaro it does not detect PostGIS version and neither does it allow me to change anything manually.

As this is a new software and the community and support is minimal still i do not know what is the right approach to solve this issue.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: What OS are you using btw?

Comment: cartaro is not ready for prime time yet as it is early beta, it pretty much breaks, only the dev even builds with suuccess and is not recommended for making your site as it has many bugs and is unstable.
If you are interested in developemnt then read and reply to the developers message board.
Personally I'm waiting to where it builds for most users most times and is stable.

Answer (score 3):

Another things that I learned (and may have relevance) is that the drupal database is also used for the postgis database, the user needs to be enabled and I believe needs to have the same credentials as the drupal user.

To further complicate things geo server needs the same default id and login as postgres admin.if postgres was installed using stack installer.

The last was more of an issue if installed with postgres stack installer on windows ( perhaps linux as well ) as it sets up the admin account in advance of cartaro ) cause you will install that next ).

The stack installer will make a drupal database and user. Cartaro looks for postgres admin, however, if that is different form the drupal user set up by postgres stack installer.

There are a lot of different ways this could be handled but it is trial and error with a lack of current documentation or much user experience to guide you.

I'm guessing linux is the way to go here currently ( and perhaps, no stack installer )

Answer (score 1):

Cartaro is still in a development stage. In fact there was a change in July that should give more precise messages in case PostGIS cannot be detected. Thus it is probably best to try a more current version of Cartaro.

You might find a hint in http://drupal.org/node/1558270. Please file a bug report in [Cartaro's issure tracker](http://drupal.org/project/issues/cartaro) if newer versions don't solve your problem so that is does not get overlooked.